# Why does Java disallow reducing visibility of parent methods, but allows increasing them?

Tags: java, inheritance

Example:

```
class Parent {
    public void func(){
        System.err.println("parnet");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    protected void func(){
        System.err.println("child");
    }
}
```

is illegal but if we switch the visibility it is legal. What's the reason why it is designed this way? I can't make much sense out of it.

Comment: This as well - http://stackoverflow.com/q/9035052/2030471

Answer (score 1):

It's because someone could be using a 'Parent' object to refer to an instance of the 'Child' object, and reducing the visibility would break the inheritance 'contract'.

Imagine if you had a class 'Cat' that extends 'Animal' which had public methods to `breathe()` and `eat()`.

Now if your 'Cat' class made `breathe()` private, then someone that has an Animal referring to your cat couldn't call `breathe()` on the cat (and we can't have unhappy cats in Java!)

Answer (score 0):

If you get an instance to the parent class , you should be able to reach all of its public methods . That's part of the contract.

The Child class has the "is a" property compared to the parent , therefore it can do at least what the Parent can do.

For example:

```
List<Parent> parents=new List<Parent>();
parents.add(new Child());
...
parents.get(0).func(); // you should always be able to call it , since it's a Parent instance .
```