# How to inherit from a base class but make some of public methods from the base class private in the derived class?

Tags: java

For example, class Base has two public methods: foo() and bar(). Class Derived is inherited from class Base (I cannot modify this class, as its a in a library I use).

In class Derived (Its in my application), I want to make foo() public but bar() private. Is the following code the correct and natural way to do this? Instead of extending it, I am creating a object and accessing only the required methods.

```
    class Base {
       public void foo();
       public void bar();
    };

    public class Derived {
         private Base base;

         public void bar() {
            base.bar();
         }
    };
```

Comment: there is no inheritance in the code you show. what do you mean, you want to make an inherited method 'private'? that is not possible

Comment: It makes no sense to make an inherited public method private in the derived class. The derived class must be able to substitute the base class. This would not work if a method from the base class is no longer available due to visibility constraints.

Comment: This is composition (eg a very simple facade or adapter), not inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reduce the visibility of a method you inherit from

So if the super method is public you cannot reduce to protected or private

This question already covers it : [Cannot reduce visibility of method inherited method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035052/cannot-reduce-visibility-of-method-inherited-method-from-parent)

Comment: if you add questions for more information, this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @sp00m noted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit from a class and reduce the visibility of the inherited methods. On the other hand, the code you are showing is not making use of inheritance. If you need to extend a class (so that you inherit all state and behavior from the base class), but also don't want to expose all inherited methods as public, here's a way to do it:

```
public final class Derived {

    private final Base base = new Base() { // extending base class here

        @Override
        public void foo() {
            Derived.this.foo();
        }

        @Override
        public void bar() {
            Derived.this.bar();
        }
    };

    public void foo() {
        // Implement foo here
    }

    private void bar() {
        // Implement bar here
    }
}
```

So the idea is to encapsulate the implementation of a class that extends `Base` in a `private final` field of a new `Derived` class that only exposes the `foo` method, while keeping the `bar` method `private`. This anonymous inner class just delegates to methods of the `Derived` class. As an extra safety measure, we are also making the `Derived` class `final`.